# Connecting android app to online mysql database

Tags: android, mysql, jdbc, mysql-odbc-connector

hi iam new to android development iam currently working on an android app that needs to connect to an online mysql database. I had experience in java application development in netbeans,I used the following code in netbeans to connect to an sql server by using jdbc driver....

```
 import java.sql.Connection;
 import java.sql.DriverManager;
 import java.sql.ResultSet;
 import java.sql.Statement;

 import net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.*;

 public void query2()
 {
 Log.i("Android"," MySQL Connect Example.");
  Connection conn = null;
 try {
 String driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
 Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
 //test = com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.class;
 String connString = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://server_ip_address  :1433/DBNAME;encrypt=fasle;user=xxxxxxxxx;password=xxxxxxxx;instance=SQLEXPRESS;";
 String username = "xxxxxx";
 String password = "xxxxxxxxxx";
 conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connString,username,password);
  Log.w("Connection","open");
 Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
 ResultSet reset = stmt.executeQuery("select * from TableName");

 //Print the data to the console
 while(reset.next()){
 Log.w("Data:",reset.getString(3));
  //              Log.w("Data",reset.getString(2));
 }
 conn.close();

   } catch (Exception e)
   {
   Log.w("Error connection","" + e.getMessage());
    }
```

but in android iam stuck at nowhere i don't know any thing about it,so can please any one write my code for a correspoding android application so that i can understand th difference ....any help would be apricited...

Answer (score 0):

You can either use jtds in android project itself(not preferred)

or

use json,xml parsing by Http(preferred)

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: why jtdc is not prefered..? i dont know how to use xml or json can you please provide me some tutorials or can u send me some tutorials on how to use jtds in android projects @Ravi Sharma

Comment: its hard to overcome connectivity issues with jtds on mobile side. This is the link for php , android connectivity http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/